# Add user to a model by clicking on a link

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I created a unique token that is link to a property, when the user goes to the link there is a button to validate is will to join this property.

Now, I am a bit confused on how to finish my code.

**Models.py :**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name="Nom de l'établissement")
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Liste des collaborateurs autorisés") 
    token = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Token") 
    payday = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Jour de paye", null=True, blank=True)
    planning = models.ImageField('Planning', null=True, blank=True )
```

**My views.py**

```
def join_property(request, property_id):
property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
contributors # now this is where I cannot figured out ...
contributors.save()
```

So I get the logic but not fully understand the middle part of my code.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add()` method on a many-to-many relationship is the one you need. It allows you to add a relationship (and it automatically saves the relationship).

```
def join_property(request, property_id):
    property = Property.objects.get(pk=property_id)
    property.contributors.add(request.user)
    ...  # don't forget to return something! (e.g. redirect or confirmation page)
```

Read all about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Don't forget: `contributors` isn't the list of contributors it's a relationship manager (`ManyRelatedManager` to be precise), similar to `objects`. So to fetch all contributors, you need to  `property.contributors.all()`. That's why you also have the methods `add()` and `set()`.